# Inject values from maven settings file

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin

My maven settings file looks like this:

```
<profiles>
   <profile>
        <id>artifactory</id>
   </profile>
 
 <properties>
    <TestProperty>test_property</TestProperty>
 </properties>

</profiles>

 <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
 </activeProfiles>

<servers>
    <server>
      <id>server_one</id>
      <username>user_one</username>
      <password>pw_one</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>server_two</id>
      <username>pw_two</username>
      <password>pw_two</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

How can I inject the server_two username and password into a pom file?

I was able to inject some of the properties for the active profile by using ${TestProperty}, but I am still trying to inject the sub values of the server element into a pom file.

Comment: Why you need it? This is available for plugins internally

Comment: I want to download a file from Artifactory (via pom file) and therefore I need username and password from Maven settings file.

Comment: Better will be use a dedicated plugin like https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin